# How to create twisted wires in Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers

This object was created in Cinema 4D. 
How can you recreate it in Blender?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it this way:

- Create a Circle, shift it from its origin in Edit mode, go back in Object mode, create an Empty on the same point as the origin of the circle. Assign an *Array* modifier to the Circle with a *Count* of 5, deactivate *Relative Offset*, activate *Object Offset* and choose the Empty. Rotate the Empty 72° on the Z axis. Apply the *Array* modifier, you now have 5 circles.
- Extrude one time your 5 circles and repeat with shift R so that you have several extrudes (of course you can also decide to make all these extrusions, or edge loops creation, on the original circle, before applying the first array).

[image]

- Assign a *Simple Deform* modifier to your object, with a *Deform Angle* of 72°. You can Apply this modifier if you want.

[image]

- Assign an *Array* modifier to your Object and choose a factor of 1 on the Z axis. Maybe enable *Merge* and *First/Last* so that the top sticks correctly to the bottom of the array copy. Choose the *Count* you want.

[image]

- Create a bezier curve, go in Edit mode and make sure the direction is the one you want, if not *W* > *Switch Directio*n. Put the Origin at its starting point.
- Put your object at the beginning of the curve.
- Assign a *Curve* modifier to your object, choose your bezier curve as the *Object*. It should follow the curve.
- You can add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object and smooth it.

[image]

Comment: great answer!! Learnt a lot

Answer (score 20):

Here is one approach using addon: **Add Curve: Extra Objects**

1) Create archimedian spiral
2) Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to toggle the Curve Spirals menu and adjust the curve
3) Bevel the curve
4) Create instance of the curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
5) Rotate <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>72</kbd> (360/5=72 if you want 5 elements)
6) Repeat 3 more times
7) You can additionally scale it (in edit mode)

[image]

Comment: @金馆长 Please don't just add **thank you**. If an answer solves your problem, you can [accept](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, another method. (This time, for a 6-fold braid, up in Z)

- Create a 6-sided circle at the origin
- Create an Empty at the origin
- Rotate the Empty by 60 in Z
- Give the circle an *Array* modifier, 6-count, Object-offset, based on the Empty
- In Edit mode, all selected, <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> drag the circle away from its origin
- Give the array a *Screw* modifier, in Z, adjusting the modifier's 'Screw' parameter for height.
- Finish with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]

The braid on the left should result. Now you have some options:

- in Edit Mode, with Pivot set to 'Median', <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> the circle to get better topology, with less-stressed quads, as in the middle.
- Delete the inner edges of the circle, and adjusting as above, bring connecting vertices together, adding  *Weld* and *Bevel* (by angle) modifiers, to get a shell that will subdivide well. (Move the subdiv to the bottom of the modifier stack)