# how to intertwine two strings together into a single string

Tags: properties

I was able to make the rope, but the result was bad, does anyone know how to make power by the function of the modifier?
[image][image][image]

Comment: maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114563/how-to-create-twisted-wires-in-blender/114566#114566

Comment: I appreciate the indication, but it's not what I'm looking for. Notice that my only more complex objects, they are already twisted, I need to twist something already twisted, you know?