# Mesh of a single twist Yarn in Blender

Tags: mesh

I am new at Blender, I want to design a mesh of a single twisted yarn, which is the best strategy to design this mesh. Sorry if my question sounds dumb.

I am attaching the picture
![enter image description here
[image]

I foud a tutorial in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cP1pY14fVC4&list=LLuORS2hOBqsUJEgE645iWDQ&index=2&t=1026s, however, I dont know how to merge the mesh.

**EDIT**
Is this mesh true, I am going to use it for physical simulation

[image]

Comment: please show an image of a single twisted yarn, how is it made exactly, several ropes? etc..

Comment: @moonboots, I am attaching the picture.

Comment: please tell me if that answer helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114563/how-to-create-twisted-wires-in-blender/114566#114566

Comment: Thanks so much, yes, indeed, I found a similar video earlier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYhIoiOnPj4. Indeed thanks for the help.

Comment: @moonboots, i am trying to follow this tutorial, which create twisted yarn, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cP1pY14fVC4, at minute: 16:50, I cannot replicate it, please see picture above, I dont know why they dont merge

Comment: you need to enable the Snap option (magnet icon) / vertex mode, (or press ctrl to enable the Snap while you move your mesh) and also the Auto Merge option, which, in 2.8, is in the 3D view N panel (top right) > Tools > Options, tell me if it works

Comment: Maybe you don't say enough, do they snap? If they do, they won't merge as long as you don't enable the auto-merge option, if you've enabled auto-merge I don't know what's the problem, maybe share your file

Comment: I am doing it again,if it did not work, I would share my file, thanks so much for help.

Comment: also, make sure you're in Vertex select mode

Comment: @moonboots, i ididnot work, after extruding, the mesh isnot converging, although I made sure to snap vertices by holding shift and move, I dont know what is the problem I missing, I am attaching the file, hope you could help me.

Comment: @moonboots, I am adding the file in the question part, thanks.

Comment: You didn't enable the Auto-Merge option (N panel > Tool > Options >  Auto-Merge, but anyway, your shape is not symmetrical, so it won't twist properly, I'm going to make a full answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a 12 vertices circle.

[image]

- Enable the *Snap* option (*Vertex* mode), or just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> when you'll need it, enable the *Auto-Merge* option.

[image]

- Duplicate your circle, with *Snap* and *Auto-Merge* it will snap and merge the vertices. Delete the inner vertices, bevel the 3 central vertices with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

- Extrude up, create horizontal edge loops with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. To make sure you don't have flipped normals, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. Back in *Object* mode, move the origin to the geometry.

[image]

- Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Angle* 120°, *Axis* Z.

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier, enable the *Merge* and *First Last* options.

[image]

- Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and also smooth it: *Object* > *Shade Smooth*.

[image]

- To make it follow a curve, give it a *Curve* modifier. Make sure that the curve's origin is at its beginning, put the object at the same point.

Comment: Thanks so much, the automerge isnot appearing in 2.8 blender , can I use ctrl+j. I am using mac. I am adding the figure in the description.

Comment: I'm also on Mac, Auto-Merge should appear once in Edit mode, are you in Edit mode?

Comment: Sorry, I am very dumb as I am still new user in blender, yes, it works, thanks.

Comment: I am stuck at the point of extruding up, I know to create a loop ctrl+N. I am adding the picture in description

Comment: Ctrl R to create new edge loop(s), but you should not completely reedit your question, please reintroduce the initial question and images

Comment: Plus, if you're not familiar yet with basic blender operations you should work on some beginners tutorials   ;)

Comment: I am going to use this mesh for physical simulation and it seems array modifier doesnot capture the vertices and edges, no mesh data point

Comment: Please see the mesh in question description, is this mesh true?

Comment: What do you mean by "true"? Maybe share your file so that we can check

Comment: I mean whether there is an actual mesh data point where I can use it for physics-based simulation. Here is the file on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UaeUTAr1J19QiWW2EnMmJqFRVxtPdx40

Comment: Not sure about your second Simpledeform, what is it for? Maybe what you should use is a Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth it, and also Object > Shade Smooth. But once you're glad with your object you can use it for physics, of course.

Comment: Yes, there are two, maybe added by mistake,but when I follow up with your steps,there is no actual mesh in the array, so I did manually by rotating the actual mesh, I dont know why the edit mode gives the mesh data point different from the object mode, I am really confused.

Comment: The mesh in stl sounds okay so far, however, the technique of array doesnot really have mesh data point, i did this one by accident, i dont know how I extended the mesh in rotation. This technique in minute: 18:40, in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cP1pY14fVC4&list=LLuORS2hOBqsUJEgE645iWDQ&index=2&t=1141s. I dont know how to rotate as he did, when I do this step, the vertices intervene.

Comment: thanks so much, it was the fourth button of subdivide surface not pressed.

Comment: at 18:40 he uses the Proportional Editing option (little blue sphere icon) with the Linear setting, but the Simple Deform modifier is more precise

Comment: I did it, I will try. A side question: How can convert the STL mesh to VTK Mesh in blender?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about these formats so I can't answer

Comment: I had another problem, I am trying to export a simple shape for testing my code, the exported is in OBJ format. Blender gives me an error that location is unknown or something related to volume, I just use simple shapes like sphere and ball. I increase the scale to100 while exporting and still the same error. Do you have any idea why I cannot get the OBJ mesh.

Comment: Maybe create a new question as it is a completely different issue   ;)