# How to twist multiple objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How would you go about making these kind of twisted objects. The twist consists of multiple objects. Somehow I can't get the result using the Twist modifier.

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114563/how-to-create-twisted-wires-in-blender/114566#114566

Comment: Just as a note: If you twist both bundles of strands in the same orientation the strands will untangle themselves very quickly. Real ropes therefore twist each consecutive bundle of strands in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just for fun you can do this procedurally :)
Start with five circles and a bezier curve and add modifiers...

1. Screw modifier
2. Array modifier
3. Curve modifier and target the Bezier curve
4. Simple deform modifier > Twist
5. Simple deform modifier > Bend

[image]

Comment: Yea... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh8eb_ACLl8 ... and a cat can do it too https://www.cat-health-detective.com/images/cotytwisted.jpg

Comment: We're lucky there isn't a rickroll modifier...

Comment: Call that _procedural_? Pah! Give it some Gorgious goodness and start with one vertex .. :D

Comment: @RobinBetts Oh, I'll get there once... just gimme 200 years to practice... :D

Comment: @Robin "Gorgious Goodness" should definitely be a technical term in procedural modeling... :)

Comment: Challenge accepted :)

Comment: I used your method, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here's but another one, with a simple vertex and a curve.

First, start with a single vertex on 0, 0, 0. (Create a cube, go into edit mode and vertex select mode, select everything and right click > Merge > At Center).

Add a displace modifier along X.

[image]

Add a screw modifier along Z to get a nice circle.

[image]

Add another Screw along Z, this time to get a cylinder. You might have to check "Flip" normals if the normals are inverted. (Viewport overlays > Face Orientation)

[image]

Add 2 displace modifiers, along X and Y, to offset the cylinder.

[image]

Add a Mirror modifier to X and Y, set to bisect along X and Y, to get this kind of clover shaped cylinder.

[image]

Add a simple deform Twist modifier. Set angle to 360°.

[image]

Add 2 Displace modifiers to X and Y, and set the offset to either 1.707 or type `1 + sqrt(0.5)` to get the exact value. (which will be rounded anyway by Blender)

[image]

Add two arrays along X and Y, set the count to 2 and the offset to relative -1.

[image]

Add a new Simple deform modifier set to Twist along Z by 360°.

[image]

Create a curve. Scale it way up. Add an Array modifier to your cylinders object and set it to "Fit Curve" and select your curve. Check "Merge".

[image]

Tweak the curve. Add a curve modifier to the base object and select the curve. You might have to tweak the Axis of the modifier.

[image]

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's another, using only the default cube and an empty. It is important that the origin is set to the 3d cursor for both cube and empty.

- Default cube

---

- [Displace Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier) to shrink the cube
- [Weld Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/weld.html#weld-modifier) to weld the cube into a single vertex.
- Displace again to move it slightly
- [Screw Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html#screw-modifier) (twice) to create a circle
- [Array Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html#array-modifier)to create a radial array from the empty
- Displace again to space the circles out. (used to scale the circles with array offset.)
- Array again to create a second radial array of the first
- [Simple Deform Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html#simple-deform-modifier) (twice). Twist, then bend.

Gif and sample file below :

[image]
*<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>*

[image]

Comment: Pretty cool starting with the default cube :). Didn't know you could use the *Displace modifier* like that. And thanks for sharing the file.

Comment: This one definitely appeals. I _mean_. Who wants all the hassle of reaching for the Shift-A _Create_ menu?

Comment: Awesome trick ! I'm stealing it for the next one :)