# How to solidify (cylindify) a screw a with cylinder instead of a rectangle?

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I need twisted cylinders instead beveled rectangles. Can I modify my current model or must I restart from scratch?

[image: picture]

The twisted cylinder tunnel I'm looking for:
[image: picture]

[image]

Comment: The version you share is entirely procedural... _all_ done with modifiers. Do you want that? The version you illustrate is not. It starts with a ready made circle.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes entirely procedural, the second picture should clarify what I mean for cylindrical form. I'm now trying https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114566/99884

Comment: Rather than duplicate, (This question may get wiped for that reason, no offence) I've posted [a further answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/212970/35559) to the link you're trying.

Comment: @RobinBetts That's the answer I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a pretty easy way to do this

First, create a circle mesh (not a sphere) and <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode. Press <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> in that order to create a face.

While in edit mode, grab the face, hit <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>2</kbd> in that order to move it to the right.

Stay in edit mode, press <kbd>period</kbd> key, and change it to 3d cursor.

Then, grab your circle, hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> in that order. Repeat this 5 times to get this:

[image]

After you get this add the screw modifier, and it should work